# jsp image display_ keep getting 0x0 size

Tags: java, css, image, jsp

I saved image files to

> src/main/webapp/resources/upload

,insert the absolute path of the image file to database and display the file by using absolute path like this:

```
<td><img src="${content_view.bFilePath}" alt="" style="width:30px;height:30px;" /></td>
```

it displays image file only when I run the project in eclipse. If I run the project on browser, I doesn't show any image and it keeps saying img src 0x0 even though I set the image size.

I tried both:

```
<img src="${content_view.bFilePath}" alt="" style="width:30px;height:30px;" />

<img src="${content_view.bFilePath}" alt="" width=100 height=100 />
```

and my path is like this:

```
C:\Users\ADMIN\workspace\RankingWeb_v5\src\main\webapp\resources\upload\Koala_20170926-22-36-04.jpg
```

I don't see any problem with the path because it is displaying the image on eclipse. 
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added

> < resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/upload/" />

on servlet_context.xml

and then changed my code to

```
<img src="<c:url value="/resources/${content_view.bFile}"/>" width="300"/>
```